# Кастомный сериализатор\десериализатор объектов

Tags: java, сериализация, десериализация, unserialize

Всем привет. Столкнулся с задачей - необходимо создать кастомный серилизатор\десерилизатор объектов.
Программа должна конвертировать объект в массив байтов и, соответственно, выполнять обратную конвертацию без использования стандартных библиотек серилизации.

Не совсем понимаю, как выполнять такую задачу.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь и примеры.

Comment: Ну посмотрите на исходники любого осуществующего сериализатора

Comment: Для начала ответьте на вопрос - в какой формат вы хотите сериализовать объект? Дело в том, что под термины "массивом байтов" или "последовательностью байтов" в принципе попадает все что угодно. Подойдет ли для вашей задачи json, xml?

Comment: Сериализованный объект должен хранится в формате byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно сложная задача. Стандартный способ реализации приблизительно такой:

1. Открываем выходной поток `OutputStream`
2. Берем класс, через рефлексию выкручиваем поля класса, если поле класса примитивный тип или некий базовый тип, а ля `String/Object` пишем поля в выходной поток с некоторым заголовком, который показывает тип записываемого поля
3. Если поле класса другой составной класс, то погружаемся в рекурсию и раскручиваем этот класс до полей (см. п.1)
4. И т.д. пока все поля всех классов не выкрутим до примитивных и базовых типов и закрываем поток

Для десериализации выкручиваем в обратном порядке, читаем заголовок, заводим примитивный/базовый тип создаем его ну и т.д.

Для понимания общего принципа работы стандартного механизма `Serializable` - исходники [ObjectOutputStream](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java) - все упирается в базовый метод `writeObject()` реализованный для всех примитивных/базовых типов Java - по сути вы должны написать что-то подобное этому.